# Зачиняти чи закривати?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, стилістика

В Інтернеті знаходжу пояснення:

- *зачинено* — про вікна, двері;
- *замкнуто, замкнено* — про замок.

У повсякденному спілкуванні ми вживаємо і *"закрити" вікно*, і *"зачинити" вікно*.

Крім цього, на одному із сайтів дають таку пораду:

> *скористайтеся доповненням OnlineCorrector, щоби перевірити інші
>   випадки слововживання та можливі помилки в тексті.*

Хочеться все-таки знати правильну відповідь без застосування будь-яких програм.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Українською «зачиняють» вертикальні речі на завісах, як от двері, браму, хвіртку, вікно.
«Замикають» на замок, клямку чи на засув.
«Закривають» щось, аби його видно не було, наприклад хусткою, а ще також те саме, що «зачиняти».
А ще: очі «заплющують», а книгу «згортають». Ще «згортають» руки (відмовляються діяти).

Answer (score 0):

Чув від викладачки в університеті ще таке:

**Закритий** магазин - магазин закритий назавжди(банкрутсво, переїхав і т.п.);

**Зачинений** магазин - графік роботи до 20:00, а зараз 21:00, тому він зараз **зачинений**, але завтра з 09:00 буде **відчинений**